# NodeJS / MongoDB: DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connectionstring

Estou com problema em:

```
let options = 'replicaSet=XPTO&readPreference=secondary';
var url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@${host}/admin?${options}`;
```

DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Mesmo usando o {useNewUrlParser: true} após ${options} continuo com o mesmo problema.
Podem ajudar?

Comment: Edite a pergunta adicionando o trecho de código em que você realiza a conexão.

Comment: Já fiz isso, não deu muito certo!

Comment: Você já editou fornecendo o trecho de código como o Luiz instruiu? Não estou vendo na sua pergunta

Comment: Sim, já coloquei var url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@${host}/admin?${options},{useNewUrlParser: true}`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não coloque o { useNewUrlParser: true } dentro da sua variável url, você deve coloca-lo como segundo parâmetro no objeto de conexão.
assim:

```
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/SeuBanco", { useNewUrlParser:true})
  .then(conn => algum código caso a conexão for ok)
  .catch(err => algum código caso de erro)
```

Repare que na primeira linha eu criei o objeto mongoCliente que importei do módulo mongodb, depois usei a função connect deste objeto para abrir a conexão, é nela que você deve especificar o useNewUrlParser como segundo parâmetro. Do jeito que você estava fazendo, colocando dentro da sua variável url ela estava indo no primeiro parâmetro.
Fonte: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#.connect
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Meus parabéns, muito bem explicado e consegui resolver muito bem! Muito obrigado!